# Assign Name to Loop

Tags: javascript

```
//Set the number of spaces in front of text
numSpaces = 20;
//
spaces = "&nbsp";
//
importantMessage = "This is a variable message that I will define";

for (var i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++)
{
//here is the output on screen
document.write(spaces)
}

//printing the full message
document.write(importantMessage);
```

I'm currently teaching myself javascript. I'm so confused if this is breaking a law in JS land, but how do I define a loop with a name? I would like to give the whole section from for (var...to write(spaces)} a name, so then I can do document.write(nameofloop + importantMessage) which of course will print out what I need. When I do define a name, somehow the loop says "undefined" before the "important message."

Unless there is a better way to loop some html code that is user defined. I want to be able to make a number of spaces before the message on my crawler message and it could vary depending on the user.

I'm confused on multiple { { } } as I will eventually make an if statement once I get this working. Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Can you post some pseudo code for what you are trying to accomplish? Also, what should `document.write(nameofloop + importantMessage)` print out?

Comment: Are you teaching yourself with any material, like a tutorial?

Comment: @SimpleCoder nameofloop is what I am trying to define a loop. Currently, if I use the code as the poster below, I still get an undefined before the first word. "document.write(writeSpaces(10) + importantMessage)" is what I am using.

Comment: @ Dave Newton - Nope, just learning as I go.

Comment: Consider a tutorial, book, etc.

Comment: What you seem to be describing is a fundamental programming concept known as a "function" (or "procedure", in some languages). If you're new to coding you can't be expected to know about functions yet, but you really should follow Dave's suggestion and work through a tutorial.

Comment: @DaveNewton So you asked me earlier if I was using a tutorial and I answered no, learning as I go. I mis-spoke though I know it doesn't matter, but I was using a website to learn as I go and force myself to type every code except the HTML layout. I got through 7 chapters today but the problem was that in EVERY website I looked and any googled site, I could not find the answer to this question. So, I am but I learn by doing and when this comes up in an advance lesson, I will remember it better because I 'did' it.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I appreciate it, but like I mentioned just now, it was something no matter how hard I tried, I couldn't find the answer, even in an online tutorial. As the coding gets more advanced, sites have less information. But I understand why both of you suggested using books or tutorial. Honestly, I can't imagine how many people you had to teach Hello world to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to "name" chunks of code for use, you're probably under-using functions. The best approach is to wrap the loop into a function:

```
function writeSpaces(numSpaces) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) {
        document.write(spaces);
    }
}
```

Then call it like

```
writeSpaces(10);
```

Comment: I still get an undefined before my first word in "importantMessage."

Comment: document.write(writeSpaces(10) + importantMessage)

Comment: @user1227249 `writeSpaces(10); document.write(importantMessage);`